# Jquery form input

Tags: jquery

For the purpose of practicing JQuery, my intention was to have a solid red 3 px border around all the "input" of the form at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mjmitche/M9R8g/

However, as you can see, there is no red border around the check boxes and radio buttons.

Can you tell me what I have done wrong?

Comment: I don't think is possible using only css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a span/div with border like this to overcome lack of styling for checkboxes in browsers.

http://jsfiddle.net/M9R8g/9/

Comment: hmm .. soz .. but i just wonder why this answer got accepted. ok: you're skinning the element surrounding the element you want to skin, but that's not what you wanted to do in the first place .. no offense though!

Comment: probably because a workaround it's better then nothing. Nobody likes to hear: there's not way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Basically checkboxes behave little bit of notoriously across browsers. You can use images to style checkboxes in a cross browser and reliable way.

Another option is to use some jquery plugin like [this](http://www.openpave.org/~reg/jqueryui-checkbox.html) one.

Answer (score 1):

did you want to make all input border become red?
try to use `class` during set up the color in CSS instead of `div`.

But if checkbox or radio button i think you can't do that by use a default package like jquery.
try to use another plugin use search engine.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing: unfortunately you cannot skin radio-buttons or checkboxes (it wouldn't work if you would add a style to them in the markup either)

Comment: but it worked for the person who's running the tutorial that I'm following.  I also added two more commands that worked for the tutor at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mjmitche/M9R8g/6/ but they don't work for me.